# SVG Cannot be aligned in the center

Tags: svg

I have been playing with this `svg` whole day but cant align it in the middle of the div. Eirther it go outside the container or descrease size to very small.

I changed `viewBox` million time and also played with css but no luck.

Please help.

```
<svg viewbox="0 0 300 300" style="border:1px solid red">
    <g>
    <path fill="#9FC1BD" d="M241.861,379.774l-0.26-13.229h-50.975l-0.448,11.762c-0.053,0.49-0.081,0.977-0.081,1.47v8.234
        c0,7.085,5.746,12.862,12.852,12.862h26.047c7.106,0,12.865-5.777,12.865-12.862v-8.234V379.774z"/>
    <path fill="#E4BA97" d="M241.565,366.13c-0.986-9.696-3.556-16.594-5.167-19.653c-0.222-0.448-5.262-6.989-5.262-15.911
        c0-6.278,0.32-14.296,0.447-16.919c0.015-0.176,0.029-0.36,0.046-0.557c1.124-14.716,4.008-24.849,10.225-24.849v-3.328
        c0-1.819-1.847-3.32-4.109-3.32h-18.159v-0.123h-25.477c-2.26,0-4.103,1.498-4.103,3.334v3.317c6.313,0,9.045,10.511,10.074,25.618
        c0.057,0.786,0.095,1.604,0.148,2.403c0.138,4.124,0.367,11.131,0.374,16.348c0,0.229,0,0.444,0,0.645
        c-0.127,6.609-3.21,12.072-3.278,12.164l0,0c0,0-4.68,8.537-6.457,20.451c-0.057,0.367-0.113,0.796-0.113,0.796l25.786,1.653
        l25.062-1.66C241.601,366.539,241.615,366.451,241.565,366.13z"/>
    <path fill="#E4BA97" d="M248.079,281.336c0,0.677-0.113,1.343-0.307,1.999l-0.25,0.649l-0.015,0.035
        c-0.757,1.787-2.192,3.053-3.87,3.68c-0.19,0.063-0.395,0.147-0.585,0.184c-1.305,0.345-2.708,0.32-4.054-0.166h-44.94
        c-0.818,0.31-1.653,0.426-2.46,0.405c-0.274-0.024-0.543-0.031-0.803-0.078c-0.061-0.01-0.127-0.01-0.176-0.018
        c-0.142-0.042-0.272-0.046-0.409-0.091c-2.009-0.473-3.778-1.869-4.656-3.917c-0.011-0.007-0.019-0.035-0.019-0.035l-0.247-0.649
        c-0.204-0.656-0.299-1.322-0.299-1.999c0-2.326,1.202-4.558,3.253-5.798c0.278-0.183,0.578-0.334,0.888-0.451l0.215-0.105h0.004
        l7.155-3.045l0.021-0.008l0.345-0.137l0.803-0.342c0.018,0,0.018,0,0.036-0.024l1.575-0.659l0.032-0.018l0.818-0.341l2.02-0.86
        c0.299-0.184,0.588-0.357,0.892-0.55c0.116-0.081,0.246-0.162,0.367-0.247c0.817-0.529,1.621-1.113,2.375-1.706
        c0.402-0.31,0.789-0.631,1.156-0.952c0.099-0.085,0.19-0.172,0.282-0.268c1.498-1.326,2.741-2.729,3.454-4.036
        c0.061-0.103,0.113-0.215,0.176-0.328c0.487-0.913,0.927-1.734,1.301-2.527c1.068-2.196,1.709-4.001,2.069-5.774
        c0.145-0.726,0.237-1.477,0.311-2.241c0.254-3.384,0.162-4.072,0.162-4.072h3.659c0,0-0.081,0.688,0.169,4.072
        c0.134,1.766,0.487,3.384,1.156,5.224c0.303,0.817,0.677,1.685,1.121,2.615c0.395,0.821,0.867,1.734,1.403,2.704
        c0.052,0.113,0.105,0.225,0.176,0.328c0.733,1.35,2.052,2.816,3.63,4.219c0.205,0.17,0.409,0.342,0.627,0.536
        c1.128,0.931,2.355,1.84,3.599,2.602c0.137,0.077,0.257,0.158,0.384,0.236c0.091,0.06,0.179,0.113,0.274,0.166l2.023,0.86
        l3.426,1.438l1.484,0.635l1.738,0.747h0.028l4.329,1.861c0.571,0.226,1.1,0.558,1.565,0.923
        C247.128,277.297,248.079,279.277,248.079,281.336z"/>
    <path opacity="0.2" fill="#231F20" d="M219.684,256.142c-1.734-0.715-3.595-1.597-4.86-2.531c-0.208-0.144-0.413-0.3-0.596-0.452
        c0.145-0.726,0.237-1.477,0.311-2.241c0.254-3.384,0.162-4.072,0.162-4.072h3.659c0,0-0.081,0.688,0.169,4.072
        C218.662,252.684,219.015,254.302,219.684,256.142z"/>
    <path fill="#9FC1BD" d="M197.947,546.743l-5.319-137.611c0,0-2.692-19.672,5.319-21.416c8.025-1.717,14.021,1.744,12.58,15.548
        c-1.449,13.802-5.245,143.479-5.245,143.479H197.947z"/>
    <path fill="#9FC1BD" d="M226.761,546.743l-4.137-145.204c0,0,0-11.396,10.349-12.435c10.362-1.033,6.217,19.682,5.872,26.929
        c-0.341,7.264-4.835,130.71-4.835,130.71H226.761z"/>
    <path fill="#5C8BAA" d="M267.811,406.101l-5.302,0.641l-2.439-18.265l-0.395-3.009l-0.159-1.22l-0.406-3.003l-13.422-100.645
        c-0.049-0.208-0.099-0.409-0.119-0.627c-0.346-2.883,1.717-5.526,4.596-5.862c2.904-0.359,5.534,1.707,5.879,4.601
        c0.036,0.274,0.036,0.567,0.029,0.838l9.446,101.893l0.286,3.024l0.102,1.191l0.289,3.017L267.811,406.101z"/>
    <path fill="#E4BA97" d="M266.055,407.411c0,0,1.784,1.309,2.535-3.425c0.747-4.745,1.149-12.403-3.648-13.433
        c-4.794-1.046-7.5,2.922-7.924,5.034c-0.416,2.136-1.015,5.079,0.007,5.343c1.025,0.268,1.53-0.863,1.53-0.863
        c-0.423,2.556-0.321,2.404-0.67,5.051c-0.261,2.002,0.205,3.754,0.898,4.015c0.469,0.176,1.093-0.335,1.093-0.335
        s-0.271,4.342,1.279,4.399c1.543,0.049,2.059-2.095,2.059-2.095s0.655,0.624,1.353,0.173
        C265.414,410.725,266.055,407.411,266.055,407.411z"/>
    <path fill="#5C8BAA" d="M168.984,406.619l5.301,0.5l1.978-18.322l0.321-3.027l0.133-1.205l0.321-3.027l10.874-100.938
        c0.046-0.208,0.078-0.409,0.099-0.634c0.282-2.89-1.854-5.467-4.745-5.742c-2.911-0.292-5.484,1.851-5.76,4.755
        c-0.021,0.282-0.021,0.557,0,0.832l-6.866,102.103l-0.208,3.011l-0.078,1.219l-0.204,3.021L168.984,406.619z"/>
    <path fill="#E4BA97" d="M170.605,408.444c0,0-1.783,1.3-2.53-3.447c-0.747-4.734-1.149-12.372,3.645-13.415
        c4.794-1.055,7.5,2.915,7.924,5.036c0.416,2.111,1.015,5.073-0.007,5.351c-1.022,0.271-1.523-0.874-1.523-0.874
        c0.409,2.556,0.318,2.407,0.659,5.041c0.269,1.998-0.208,3.771-0.899,4.024c-0.465,0.176-1.1-0.328-1.1-0.328
        s0.269,4.343-1.265,4.402c-1.547,0.049-2.069-2.114-2.069-2.114s-0.642,0.641-1.351,0.19
        C171.247,411.769,170.605,408.444,170.605,408.444z"/>
    <path opacity="0.54" fill="#A87C4F" d="M223.575,226.767c-1.375-0.558-2.679-1.255-3.747-2.055
        c-0.412-0.332-0.807-0.642-1.173-0.974c0.007-0.049,0.007-0.105,0.014-0.165c0.247-3.359,0.172-4.043,0.172-4.043h4.072
        C222.913,219.53,222.68,222.793,223.575,226.767z"/>
    <path fill="#E7C1A5" d="M196.259,229.244v12.76c0,0,0.353,4.663,7.247,7.433c6.908,2.76,18.649,2.936,24.518,0.166
        c5.523-2.608,8.283-4.653,8.452-11.395c0.176-6.733,0-31.399,0-31.399s-1.826-12.95-20.062-12.95
        c-18.248,0-20.154,13.817-20.154,20.183C196.259,220.439,196.259,229.244,196.259,229.244z"/>
    <path fill="#E7C1A5" d="M239.74,226.245c0,2.234-1.494,4.082-3.335,4.082c-1.843,0-3.333-1.848-3.333-4.082
        c0-2.263,1.491-4.092,3.333-4.092C238.246,222.153,239.74,223.982,239.74,226.245z"/>
    <path fill="#E7C1A5" d="M199.378,226.245c0,2.234-1.501,4.082-3.341,4.082c-1.844,0-3.331-1.848-3.331-4.082
        c0-2.263,1.487-4.092,3.331-4.092C197.876,222.153,199.378,223.982,199.378,226.245z"/>
    <path fill="#9B8579" d="M229.44,213.372c-0.733-2.055-3.37-2.985-5.875-2.083l-0.204-0.578c2.815-0.987,5.791,0.099,6.644,2.453
        L229.44,213.372z"/>
    <path fill="#9B8579" d="M209.554,212.495l0.571,0.198c-0.416,1.17-1.347,2.051-2.612,2.516c-1.244,0.452-2.682,0.441-4.036-0.052
        l0.205-0.579c1.212,0.441,2.51,0.469,3.623,0.06C208.405,214.222,209.202,213.472,209.554,212.495z"/>
    <path fill="#F1F2F2" d="M209.554,221.24c0,1.279-1.033,2.319-2.309,2.319c-1.279,0-2.309-1.041-2.309-2.319
        c0-1.251,1.03-2.298,2.309-2.298C208.521,218.941,209.554,219.988,209.554,221.24z"/>
    <path fill="#F1F2F2" d="M226.98,220.993c0,1.301-1.043,2.327-2.341,2.327c-1.286,0-2.333-1.026-2.333-2.327
        c0-1.3,1.047-2.326,2.333-2.326C225.937,218.667,226.98,219.692,226.98,220.993z"/>
    <path fill="#58595B" d="M208.556,221.24c0,0.737-0.584,1.322-1.311,1.322c-0.733,0-1.322-0.585-1.322-1.322
        c0-0.712,0.589-1.301,1.322-1.301C207.972,219.939,208.556,220.527,208.556,221.24z"/>
    <path fill="#58595B" d="M226.057,220.993c0,0.737-0.592,1.336-1.333,1.336c-0.733,0-1.326-0.6-1.326-1.336
        c0-0.733,0.592-1.321,1.326-1.321C225.465,219.671,226.057,220.26,226.057,220.993z"/>
    <path fill="#A5826A" d="M236.448,222.029c-0.021-0.884-0.733-1.589-1.615-1.589c-0.874,0-1.585,0.705-1.593,1.589l0,0v4.882
        c0,2.27-1.854,4.12-4.121,4.12H203.4c-2.267,0-4.109-1.85-4.109-4.12v-4.882h-0.004c-0.035-0.853-0.737-1.533-1.594-1.533
        c-0.849,0-1.54,0.681-1.582,1.533h-0.028v17.483c0,11.138,9.03,20.168,20.182,20.168c11.152,0,20.183-9.031,20.183-20.168V222.029
        L236.448,222.029z"/>
    <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M207.686,232.84h17.024c0,0,0.353,9.777-8.509,9.89C207.341,242.839,207.686,232.84,207.686,232.84z"/>
    <path opacity="0.2" fill="#231F20" d="M219.483,232.089c0,2.059-1.667,3.726-3.729,3.726l0,0c-2.062,0-3.726-1.667-3.726-3.726
        c0,0-0.303-15.041,2.954-15.086c3.264-0.046,1.932-0.046,1.932-0.046C218.965,216.957,219.483,232.089,219.483,232.089z"/>
    <path fill="#E7C1A5" d="M219.103,230.168c0,1.847-1.501,3.341-3.348,3.341l0,0c-1.84,0-3.342-1.495-3.342-3.341
        c0,0-0.261-13.476,2.654-13.528c2.915-0.025,1.727-0.025,1.727-0.025C218.641,216.615,219.103,230.168,219.103,230.168z"/>
    <path fill="#A5826A" d="M262.826,198.491c-0.317-1.255-1.607-2.005-2.855-1.678c-0.416,0.089-0.761,0.307-1.036,0.572
        c-0.289-0.173-0.599-0.296-0.938-0.367c0.092-0.363,0.099-0.765,0-1.177c-0.303-1.131-1.36-1.847-2.489-1.749
        c0-0.183-0.013-0.373-0.066-0.553c-0.184-0.723-0.681-1.293-1.311-1.561c0.61-0.567,0.892-1.442,0.672-2.306
        c-0.324-1.254-1.607-2.012-2.869-1.691c-0.599,0.145-1.079,0.532-1.381,1.015c-0.36-0.733-1.065-1.223-1.854-1.315
        c-0.014-0.042-0.014-0.099-0.032-0.133c-0.42-1.625-1.893-2.658-3.479-2.609c-0.176-1.451-1.244-2.679-2.731-3.002
        c-0.709-0.134-1.396-0.074-2.017,0.169c0.286-0.395,0.504-0.846,0.604-1.354c0.415-1.889-0.783-3.761-2.679-4.169
        c-1.89-0.412-3.765,0.786-4.18,2.661c-0.134,0.628-0.092,1.23,0.07,1.774c-0.437,0.257-0.817,0.605-1.107,1.018
        c-0.437-0.387-0.973-0.669-1.585-0.792c-1.702-0.391-3.374,0.539-4.011,2.104c-0.247-0.106-0.508-0.205-0.775-0.265
        c-1.093-0.243-2.165,0.06-2.968,0.705c-0.345-1.206-1.318-2.165-2.629-2.454c-1.893-0.416-3.761,0.79-4.174,2.679
        c-0.197,0.898-0.031,1.793,0.403,2.524c-0.678,0-1.333,0.19-1.89,0.539c-0.071-0.007-0.142-0.032-0.219-0.007
        c0.43-0.754,0.606-1.635,0.402-2.541c-0.402-1.893-2.284-3.091-4.184-2.687c-1.29,0.296-2.266,1.251-2.608,2.468
        c-0.807-0.663-1.886-0.962-2.968-0.715c-0.278,0.052-0.542,0.162-0.786,0.282c-0.627-1.564-2.312-2.502-4.011-2.129
        c-0.613,0.142-1.145,0.413-1.585,0.825c-0.088-0.497-0.388-0.923-0.825-1.178c-4-2.622-6.753,0.825-6.457,1.224
        c-0.631-0.236-1.318-0.306-2.023-0.145c-1.607,0.349-2.721,1.734-2.763,3.334c-1.614-0.147-3.145,0.846-3.659,2.433
        c-0.715,0.119-1.347,0.588-1.665,1.258c-0.313-0.472-0.796-0.832-1.389-0.997c-1.258-0.324-2.548,0.426-2.869,1.678
        c-0.219,0.881,0.063,1.738,0.677,2.323c-0.638,0.279-1.135,0.821-1.318,1.554c-0.053,0.18-0.074,0.367-0.074,0.543
        c-1.121-0.091-2.182,0.627-2.485,1.755c-0.103,0.409-0.088,0.814,0.007,1.205c-0.332,0.046-0.652,0.163-0.938,0.35
        c-0.282-0.265-0.638-0.476-1.033-0.582c-1.266-0.328-2.542,0.434-2.869,1.699c-0.328,1.248,0.427,2.53,1.688,2.862
        c0.027,0,0.049,0,0.066,0.01c-0.084,0.575-0.024,1.125,0.145,1.639c-0.07,1.1,0.656,2.136,1.763,2.418
        c0.437,0.102,0.877,0.077,1.276-0.053c0.113,0.018,0.226,0.018,0.335,0.018c0.021,0.159,0.067,0.299,0.102,0.423
        c-0.278,0.381-0.5,0.796-0.627,1.254c-0.5,1.878,0.614,3.821,2.488,4.304c0.063,0.024,0.109,0.024,0.166,0.039
        c0.208,0.799,0.828,1.479,1.682,1.685c0.444,0.126,0.88,0.091,1.289-0.046c0.049,0.081,0.106,0.13,0.156,0.19
        c-0.275,1.244,0.465,2.481,1.698,2.815c0.607,0.152,1.195,0.05,1.703-0.218c0.116,0.25,0.257,0.465,0.419,0.67
        c-0.744,0.441-1.325,1.178-1.565,2.097c-0.501,1.882,0.62,3.789,2.491,4.29c0.783,0.211,1.583,0.127,2.274-0.169
        c-0.036,0.091-0.071,0.211-0.085,0.307c-0.512,1.886,0.617,3.796,2.488,4.289c1.882,0.501,3.8-0.613,4.3-2.506
        c0.021-0.081,0.049-0.19,0.063-0.296c0.184,0.088,0.374,0.166,0.578,0.215c1.883,0.49,3.8-0.62,4.304-2.492
        c0.441-1.682-0.413-3.401-1.946-4.103c0.014-0.549-0.099-1.089-0.321-1.568c0.987-0.406,1.787-1.248,2.076-2.355
        c0.285-1.068,0.039-2.157-0.568-2.988c0.142-0.244,0.254-0.526,0.332-0.79c0.113-0.444,0.141-0.867,0.091-1.293
        c1.53-0.024,2.918-1.068,3.328-2.611c0.028-0.106,0.042-0.233,0.07-0.37c0.367,0.042,0.733,0.035,1.121-0.053
        c0.796-0.162,1.474-0.606,1.949-1.191c0.811,0.994,2.147,1.516,3.497,1.219c1.822-0.387,2.989-2.122,2.718-3.951
        c1.656-0.561,2.665-2.306,2.288-4.067c-0.092-0.385-0.229-0.73-0.434-1.043c1.575-0.476,2.608-1.953,2.53-3.55
        c0.106-0.024,0.198-0.032,0.304-0.056c0.289-0.057,0.549-0.163,0.803-0.279c0.007,1.522,0.997,2.915,2.523,3.345
        c-0.204,0.324-0.341,0.687-0.426,1.089c-0.391,1.737,0.617,3.474,2.274,4.063c-0.276,1.794,0.902,3.556,2.714,3.938
        c1.354,0.31,2.686-0.223,3.497-1.251c0.479,0.61,1.156,1.05,1.959,1.212c0.311,0.074,0.614,0.084,0.923,0.074
        c0.007,0.01,0.007,0.01,0.007,0.01c0.406,1.572,1.79,2.591,3.327,2.626c-0.042,0.412-0.021,0.821,0.092,1.272
        c0.07,0.269,0.19,0.55,0.328,0.8c-0.603,0.821-0.856,1.911-0.563,2.975c0.289,1.121,1.081,1.977,2.083,2.358
        c-0.222,0.479-0.338,1.021-0.331,1.579c-1.523,0.711-2.383,2.421-1.935,4.092c0.49,1.885,2.421,2.999,4.296,2.506
        c0.197-0.061,0.395-0.113,0.585-0.205c0.014,0.092,0.029,0.188,0.056,0.296c0.494,1.868,2.418,2.992,4.3,2.485
        c1.875-0.483,2.993-2.4,2.503-4.29c-0.035-0.096-0.067-0.183-0.106-0.282c0.698,0.282,1.487,0.356,2.28,0.148
        c1.872-0.501,2.993-2.411,2.503-4.29c-0.25-0.923-0.832-1.649-1.579-2.104c0.138-0.169,0.25-0.331,0.363-0.519
        c0.542,0.423,1.29,0.6,2.016,0.423c1.254-0.328,2.009-1.604,1.688-2.873c-0.018-0.074-0.032-0.134-0.067-0.198
        c0.465,0.198,1.001,0.254,1.53,0.113c1.007-0.271,1.685-1.138,1.741-2.125c1.776-0.564,2.812-2.422,2.333-4.241
        c-0.084-0.325-0.218-0.627-0.38-0.899c0.063-0.18,0.113-0.367,0.127-0.567c0.483,0.229,1.036,0.3,1.597,0.134
        c1.259-0.311,2.016-1.608,1.695-2.845c-0.028-0.091-0.06-0.183-0.099-0.264c0.071-0.3,0.099-0.599,0.084-0.91
        c0.099,0,0.198-0.007,0.289-0.035C262.404,201.039,263.165,199.739,262.826,198.491z M203.364,195.478
        c0.021,0.052,0.021,0.12,0.029,0.169c0.021,0.067,0.042,0.12,0.06,0.194c-0.018,0.021-0.038,0.029-0.067,0.046
        c-0.032-0.049-0.063-0.12-0.098-0.172C203.322,195.622,203.34,195.555,203.364,195.478z M199.015,187.19
        c0.021,0.032,0.046,0.057,0.078,0.103c-0.113,0.029-0.222,0.039-0.325,0.091C198.853,187.322,198.938,187.265,199.015,187.19z
         M177.408,199.256c-0.024,0.071-0.039,0.159-0.039,0.226c-0.018-0.066-0.031-0.141-0.053-0.201
        C177.352,199.281,177.384,199.256,177.408,199.256z M233.691,186.659c0.081,0.077,0.166,0.148,0.25,0.208
        c-0.109-0.024-0.214-0.074-0.328-0.103C233.642,186.736,233.67,186.718,233.691,186.659z M229.314,195.118
        c0.01-0.042,0.014-0.098,0.028-0.151c0.028,0.07,0.056,0.151,0.085,0.243c-0.043,0.032-0.071,0.092-0.106,0.163
        c-0.018-0.025-0.042-0.025-0.063-0.039C229.278,195.266,229.303,195.186,229.314,195.118z"/>
    <path fill="#E6E7E8" d="M246.641,273.381v97.775h-59.652v-97.775l17.99-7.617c1.77,4.177,6.458,7.155,11.981,7.155
        c5.484,0,10.154-2.936,11.949-7.046L246.641,273.381z"/>
    <polygon fill="#5C8BAA" points="211.517,281.653 202.843,266.606 184.395,274.403 184.395,391.522 211.517,391.522     "/>
    <polygon fill="#5C8BAA" points="231.112,266.733 222.43,281.77 222.43,391.649 249.553,391.649 249.553,274.523    "/>
    <polygon fill="#517B93" points="211.503,281.664 197.281,267.541 204.443,262.764 213.516,276.179     "/>
    <polygon opacity="0.2" fill="#231F20" points="206.491,282.086 197.323,267.523 203.957,263.339 213.562,276.165   "/>
    <polygon fill="#5C8BAA" points="206.389,280.949 197.323,267.523 204.479,262.758 213.562,276.165     "/>
    <polygon fill="#517B93" points="222.462,281.664 236.694,267.541 229.532,262.764 220.467,276.179     "/>
    <polygon opacity="0.2" fill="#231F20" points="227.481,282.086 236.652,267.523 230.018,263.339 220.42,276.165    "/>
    <polygon fill="#5C8BAA" points="227.579,280.949 236.652,267.523 229.494,262.758 220.42,276.165  "/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your paths are drawn on that side of the viewbox.

all your paths start with M[x], where x is always closer to 300 than 0.

M stands for MoveTo. meaning, you're starting at the right side.

Adding `<g transform="translate(-75)">` seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

The bounding box of the "man" image is:

```
x: 166.92599487304688
y: 176.1710205078125
width: 102.81298828125
height: 370.572021484375
```

So an appropriate bounding box would be:

```
viewBox="166 176 104 371"
```

Then if you surround it with a `<div>` of your desired size, it will be automatically centred.

Demo:

```css
DIV {
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
```

```html
<div>

<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="166 176 104 371" style="border:1px solid red">
    <g>
    <path fill="#9FC1BD" d="M241.861,379.774l-0.26-13.229h-50.975l-0.448,11.762c-0.053,0.49-0.081,0.977-0.081,1.47v8.234
        c0,7.085,5.746,12.862,12.852,12.862h26.047c7.106,0,12.865-5.777,12.865-12.862v-8.234V379.774z"/>
    <path fill="#E4BA97" d="M241.565,366.13c-0.986-9.696-3.556-16.594-5.167-19.653c-0.222-0.448-5.262-6.989-5.262-15.911
        c0-6.278,0.32-14.296,0.447-16.919c0.015-0.176,0.029-0.36,0.046-0.557c1.124-14.716,4.008-24.849,10.225-24.849v-3.328
        c0-1.819-1.847-3.32-4.109-3.32h-18.159v-0.123h-25.477c-2.26,0-4.103,1.498-4.103,3.334v3.317c6.313,0,9.045,10.511,10.074,25.618
        c0.057,0.786,0.095,1.604,0.148,2.403c0.138,4.124,0.367,11.131,0.374,16.348c0,0.229,0,0.444,0,0.645
        c-0.127,6.609-3.21,12.072-3.278,12.164l0,0c0,0-4.68,8.537-6.457,20.451c-0.057,0.367-0.113,0.796-0.113,0.796l25.786,1.653
        l25.062-1.66C241.601,366.539,241.615,366.451,241.565,366.13z"/>
    <path fill="#E4BA97" d="M248.079,281.336c0,0.677-0.113,1.343-0.307,1.999l-0.25,0.649l-0.015,0.035
        c-0.757,1.787-2.192,3.053-3.87,3.68c-0.19,0.063-0.395,0.147-0.585,0.184c-1.305,0.345-2.708,0.32-4.054-0.166h-44.94
        c-0.818,0.31-1.653,0.426-2.46,0.405c-0.274-0.024-0.543-0.031-0.803-0.078c-0.061-0.01-0.127-0.01-0.176-0.018
        c-0.142-0.042-0.272-0.046-0.409-0.091c-2.009-0.473-3.778-1.869-4.656-3.917c-0.011-0.007-0.019-0.035-0.019-0.035l-0.247-0.649
        c-0.204-0.656-0.299-1.322-0.299-1.999c0-2.326,1.202-4.558,3.253-5.798c0.278-0.183,0.578-0.334,0.888-0.451l0.215-0.105h0.004
        l7.155-3.045l0.021-0.008l0.345-0.137l0.803-0.342c0.018,0,0.018,0,0.036-0.024l1.575-0.659l0.032-0.018l0.818-0.341l2.02-0.86
        c0.299-0.184,0.588-0.357,0.892-0.55c0.116-0.081,0.246-0.162,0.367-0.247c0.817-0.529,1.621-1.113,2.375-1.706
        c0.402-0.31,0.789-0.631,1.156-0.952c0.099-0.085,0.19-0.172,0.282-0.268c1.498-1.326,2.741-2.729,3.454-4.036
        c0.061-0.103,0.113-0.215,0.176-0.328c0.487-0.913,0.927-1.734,1.301-2.527c1.068-2.196,1.709-4.001,2.069-5.774
        c0.145-0.726,0.237-1.477,0.311-2.241c0.254-3.384,0.162-4.072,0.162-4.072h3.659c0,0-0.081,0.688,0.169,4.072
        c0.134,1.766,0.487,3.384,1.156,5.224c0.303,0.817,0.677,1.685,1.121,2.615c0.395,0.821,0.867,1.734,1.403,2.704
        c0.052,0.113,0.105,0.225,0.176,0.328c0.733,1.35,2.052,2.816,3.63,4.219c0.205,0.17,0.409,0.342,0.627,0.536
        c1.128,0.931,2.355,1.84,3.599,2.602c0.137,0.077,0.257,0.158,0.384,0.236c0.091,0.06,0.179,0.113,0.274,0.166l2.023,0.86
        l3.426,1.438l1.484,0.635l1.738,0.747h0.028l4.329,1.861c0.571,0.226,1.1,0.558,1.565,0.923
        C247.128,277.297,248.079,279.277,248.079,281.336z"/>
    <path opacity="0.2" fill="#231F20" d="M219.684,256.142c-1.734-0.715-3.595-1.597-4.86-2.531c-0.208-0.144-0.413-0.3-0.596-0.452
        c0.145-0.726,0.237-1.477,0.311-2.241c0.254-3.384,0.162-4.072,0.162-4.072h3.659c0,0-0.081,0.688,0.169,4.072
        C218.662,252.684,219.015,254.302,219.684,256.142z"/>
    <path fill="#9FC1BD" d="M197.947,546.743l-5.319-137.611c0,0-2.692-19.672,5.319-21.416c8.025-1.717,14.021,1.744,12.58,15.548
        c-1.449,13.802-5.245,143.479-5.245,143.479H197.947z"/>
    <path fill="#9FC1BD" d="M226.761,546.743l-4.137-145.204c0,0,0-11.396,10.349-12.435c10.362-1.033,6.217,19.682,5.872,26.929
        c-0.341,7.264-4.835,130.71-4.835,130.71H226.761z"/>
    <path fill="#5C8BAA" d="M267.811,406.101l-5.302,0.641l-2.439-18.265l-0.395-3.009l-0.159-1.22l-0.406-3.003l-13.422-100.645
        c-0.049-0.208-0.099-0.409-0.119-0.627c-0.346-2.883,1.717-5.526,4.596-5.862c2.904-0.359,5.534,1.707,5.879,4.601
        c0.036,0.274,0.036,0.567,0.029,0.838l9.446,101.893l0.286,3.024l0.102,1.191l0.289,3.017L267.811,406.101z"/>
    <path fill="#E4BA97" d="M266.055,407.411c0,0,1.784,1.309,2.535-3.425c0.747-4.745,1.149-12.403-3.648-13.433
        c-4.794-1.046-7.5,2.922-7.924,5.034c-0.416,2.136-1.015,5.079,0.007,5.343c1.025,0.268,1.53-0.863,1.53-0.863
        c-0.423,2.556-0.321,2.404-0.67,5.051c-0.261,2.002,0.205,3.754,0.898,4.015c0.469,0.176,1.093-0.335,1.093-0.335
        s-0.271,4.342,1.279,4.399c1.543,0.049,2.059-2.095,2.059-2.095s0.655,0.624,1.353,0.173
        C265.414,410.725,266.055,407.411,266.055,407.411z"/>
    <path fill="#5C8BAA" d="M168.984,406.619l5.301,0.5l1.978-18.322l0.321-3.027l0.133-1.205l0.321-3.027l10.874-100.938
        c0.046-0.208,0.078-0.409,0.099-0.634c0.282-2.89-1.854-5.467-4.745-5.742c-2.911-0.292-5.484,1.851-5.76,4.755
        c-0.021,0.282-0.021,0.557,0,0.832l-6.866,102.103l-0.208,3.011l-0.078,1.219l-0.204,3.021L168.984,406.619z"/>
    <path fill="#E4BA97" d="M170.605,408.444c0,0-1.783,1.3-2.53-3.447c-0.747-4.734-1.149-12.372,3.645-13.415
        c4.794-1.055,7.5,2.915,7.924,5.036c0.416,2.111,1.015,5.073-0.007,5.351c-1.022,0.271-1.523-0.874-1.523-0.874
        c0.409,2.556,0.318,2.407,0.659,5.041c0.269,1.998-0.208,3.771-0.899,4.024c-0.465,0.176-1.1-0.328-1.1-0.328
        s0.269,4.343-1.265,4.402c-1.547,0.049-2.069-2.114-2.069-2.114s-0.642,0.641-1.351,0.19
        C171.247,411.769,170.605,408.444,170.605,408.444z"/>
    <path opacity="0.54" fill="#A87C4F" d="M223.575,226.767c-1.375-0.558-2.679-1.255-3.747-2.055
        c-0.412-0.332-0.807-0.642-1.173-0.974c0.007-0.049,0.007-0.105,0.014-0.165c0.247-3.359,0.172-4.043,0.172-4.043h4.072
        C222.913,219.53,222.68,222.793,223.575,226.767z"/>
    <path fill="#E7C1A5" d="M196.259,229.244v12.76c0,0,0.353,4.663,7.247,7.433c6.908,2.76,18.649,2.936,24.518,0.166
        c5.523-2.608,8.283-4.653,8.452-11.395c0.176-6.733,0-31.399,0-31.399s-1.826-12.95-20.062-12.95
        c-18.248,0-20.154,13.817-20.154,20.183C196.259,220.439,196.259,229.244,196.259,229.244z"/>
    <path fill="#E7C1A5" d="M239.74,226.245c0,2.234-1.494,4.082-3.335,4.082c-1.843,0-3.333-1.848-3.333-4.082
        c0-2.263,1.491-4.092,3.333-4.092C238.246,222.153,239.74,223.982,239.74,226.245z"/>
    <path fill="#E7C1A5" d="M199.378,226.245c0,2.234-1.501,4.082-3.341,4.082c-1.844,0-3.331-1.848-3.331-4.082
        c0-2.263,1.487-4.092,3.331-4.092C197.876,222.153,199.378,223.982,199.378,226.245z"/>
    <path fill="#9B8579" d="M229.44,213.372c-0.733-2.055-3.37-2.985-5.875-2.083l-0.204-0.578c2.815-0.987,5.791,0.099,6.644,2.453
        L229.44,213.372z"/>
    <path fill="#9B8579" d="M209.554,212.495l0.571,0.198c-0.416,1.17-1.347,2.051-2.612,2.516c-1.244,0.452-2.682,0.441-4.036-0.052
        l0.205-0.579c1.212,0.441,2.51,0.469,3.623,0.06C208.405,214.222,209.202,213.472,209.554,212.495z"/>
    <path fill="#F1F2F2" d="M209.554,221.24c0,1.279-1.033,2.319-2.309,2.319c-1.279,0-2.309-1.041-2.309-2.319
        c0-1.251,1.03-2.298,2.309-2.298C208.521,218.941,209.554,219.988,209.554,221.24z"/>
    <path fill="#F1F2F2" d="M226.98,220.993c0,1.301-1.043,2.327-2.341,2.327c-1.286,0-2.333-1.026-2.333-2.327
        c0-1.3,1.047-2.326,2.333-2.326C225.937,218.667,226.98,219.692,226.98,220.993z"/>
    <path fill="#58595B" d="M208.556,221.24c0,0.737-0.584,1.322-1.311,1.322c-0.733,0-1.322-0.585-1.322-1.322
        c0-0.712,0.589-1.301,1.322-1.301C207.972,219.939,208.556,220.527,208.556,221.24z"/>
    <path fill="#58595B" d="M226.057,220.993c0,0.737-0.592,1.336-1.333,1.336c-0.733,0-1.326-0.6-1.326-1.336
        c0-0.733,0.592-1.321,1.326-1.321C225.465,219.671,226.057,220.26,226.057,220.993z"/>
    <path fill="#A5826A" d="M236.448,222.029c-0.021-0.884-0.733-1.589-1.615-1.589c-0.874,0-1.585,0.705-1.593,1.589l0,0v4.882
        c0,2.27-1.854,4.12-4.121,4.12H203.4c-2.267,0-4.109-1.85-4.109-4.12v-4.882h-0.004c-0.035-0.853-0.737-1.533-1.594-1.533
        c-0.849,0-1.54,0.681-1.582,1.533h-0.028v17.483c0,11.138,9.03,20.168,20.182,20.168c11.152,0,20.183-9.031,20.183-20.168V222.029
        L236.448,222.029z"/>
    <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M207.686,232.84h17.024c0,0,0.353,9.777-8.509,9.89C207.341,242.839,207.686,232.84,207.686,232.84z"/>
    <path opacity="0.2" fill="#231F20" d="M219.483,232.089c0,2.059-1.667,3.726-3.729,3.726l0,0c-2.062,0-3.726-1.667-3.726-3.726
        c0,0-0.303-15.041,2.954-15.086c3.264-0.046,1.932-0.046,1.932-0.046C218.965,216.957,219.483,232.089,219.483,232.089z"/>
    <path fill="#E7C1A5" d="M219.103,230.168c0,1.847-1.501,3.341-3.348,3.341l0,0c-1.84,0-3.342-1.495-3.342-3.341
        c0,0-0.261-13.476,2.654-13.528c2.915-0.025,1.727-0.025,1.727-0.025C218.641,216.615,219.103,230.168,219.103,230.168z"/>
    <path fill="#A5826A" d="M262.826,198.491c-0.317-1.255-1.607-2.005-2.855-1.678c-0.416,0.089-0.761,0.307-1.036,0.572
        c-0.289-0.173-0.599-0.296-0.938-0.367c0.092-0.363,0.099-0.765,0-1.177c-0.303-1.131-1.36-1.847-2.489-1.749
        c0-0.183-0.013-0.373-0.066-0.553c-0.184-0.723-0.681-1.293-1.311-1.561c0.61-0.567,0.892-1.442,0.672-2.306
        c-0.324-1.254-1.607-2.012-2.869-1.691c-0.599,0.145-1.079,0.532-1.381,1.015c-0.36-0.733-1.065-1.223-1.854-1.315
        c-0.014-0.042-0.014-0.099-0.032-0.133c-0.42-1.625-1.893-2.658-3.479-2.609c-0.176-1.451-1.244-2.679-2.731-3.002
        c-0.709-0.134-1.396-0.074-2.017,0.169c0.286-0.395,0.504-0.846,0.604-1.354c0.415-1.889-0.783-3.761-2.679-4.169
        c-1.89-0.412-3.765,0.786-4.18,2.661c-0.134,0.628-0.092,1.23,0.07,1.774c-0.437,0.257-0.817,0.605-1.107,1.018
        c-0.437-0.387-0.973-0.669-1.585-0.792c-1.702-0.391-3.374,0.539-4.011,2.104c-0.247-0.106-0.508-0.205-0.775-0.265
        c-1.093-0.243-2.165,0.06-2.968,0.705c-0.345-1.206-1.318-2.165-2.629-2.454c-1.893-0.416-3.761,0.79-4.174,2.679
        c-0.197,0.898-0.031,1.793,0.403,2.524c-0.678,0-1.333,0.19-1.89,0.539c-0.071-0.007-0.142-0.032-0.219-0.007
        c0.43-0.754,0.606-1.635,0.402-2.541c-0.402-1.893-2.284-3.091-4.184-2.687c-1.29,0.296-2.266,1.251-2.608,2.468
        c-0.807-0.663-1.886-0.962-2.968-0.715c-0.278,0.052-0.542,0.162-0.786,0.282c-0.627-1.564-2.312-2.502-4.011-2.129
        c-0.613,0.142-1.145,0.413-1.585,0.825c-0.088-0.497-0.388-0.923-0.825-1.178c-4-2.622-6.753,0.825-6.457,1.224
        c-0.631-0.236-1.318-0.306-2.023-0.145c-1.607,0.349-2.721,1.734-2.763,3.334c-1.614-0.147-3.145,0.846-3.659,2.433
        c-0.715,0.119-1.347,0.588-1.665,1.258c-0.313-0.472-0.796-0.832-1.389-0.997c-1.258-0.324-2.548,0.426-2.869,1.678
        c-0.219,0.881,0.063,1.738,0.677,2.323c-0.638,0.279-1.135,0.821-1.318,1.554c-0.053,0.18-0.074,0.367-0.074,0.543
        c-1.121-0.091-2.182,0.627-2.485,1.755c-0.103,0.409-0.088,0.814,0.007,1.205c-0.332,0.046-0.652,0.163-0.938,0.35
        c-0.282-0.265-0.638-0.476-1.033-0.582c-1.266-0.328-2.542,0.434-2.869,1.699c-0.328,1.248,0.427,2.53,1.688,2.862
        c0.027,0,0.049,0,0.066,0.01c-0.084,0.575-0.024,1.125,0.145,1.639c-0.07,1.1,0.656,2.136,1.763,2.418
        c0.437,0.102,0.877,0.077,1.276-0.053c0.113,0.018,0.226,0.018,0.335,0.018c0.021,0.159,0.067,0.299,0.102,0.423
        c-0.278,0.381-0.5,0.796-0.627,1.254c-0.5,1.878,0.614,3.821,2.488,4.304c0.063,0.024,0.109,0.024,0.166,0.039
        c0.208,0.799,0.828,1.479,1.682,1.685c0.444,0.126,0.88,0.091,1.289-0.046c0.049,0.081,0.106,0.13,0.156,0.19
        c-0.275,1.244,0.465,2.481,1.698,2.815c0.607,0.152,1.195,0.05,1.703-0.218c0.116,0.25,0.257,0.465,0.419,0.67
        c-0.744,0.441-1.325,1.178-1.565,2.097c-0.501,1.882,0.62,3.789,2.491,4.29c0.783,0.211,1.583,0.127,2.274-0.169
        c-0.036,0.091-0.071,0.211-0.085,0.307c-0.512,1.886,0.617,3.796,2.488,4.289c1.882,0.501,3.8-0.613,4.3-2.506
        c0.021-0.081,0.049-0.19,0.063-0.296c0.184,0.088,0.374,0.166,0.578,0.215c1.883,0.49,3.8-0.62,4.304-2.492
        c0.441-1.682-0.413-3.401-1.946-4.103c0.014-0.549-0.099-1.089-0.321-1.568c0.987-0.406,1.787-1.248,2.076-2.355
        c0.285-1.068,0.039-2.157-0.568-2.988c0.142-0.244,0.254-0.526,0.332-0.79c0.113-0.444,0.141-0.867,0.091-1.293
        c1.53-0.024,2.918-1.068,3.328-2.611c0.028-0.106,0.042-0.233,0.07-0.37c0.367,0.042,0.733,0.035,1.121-0.053
        c0.796-0.162,1.474-0.606,1.949-1.191c0.811,0.994,2.147,1.516,3.497,1.219c1.822-0.387,2.989-2.122,2.718-3.951
        c1.656-0.561,2.665-2.306,2.288-4.067c-0.092-0.385-0.229-0.73-0.434-1.043c1.575-0.476,2.608-1.953,2.53-3.55
        c0.106-0.024,0.198-0.032,0.304-0.056c0.289-0.057,0.549-0.163,0.803-0.279c0.007,1.522,0.997,2.915,2.523,3.345
        c-0.204,0.324-0.341,0.687-0.426,1.089c-0.391,1.737,0.617,3.474,2.274,4.063c-0.276,1.794,0.902,3.556,2.714,3.938
        c1.354,0.31,2.686-0.223,3.497-1.251c0.479,0.61,1.156,1.05,1.959,1.212c0.311,0.074,0.614,0.084,0.923,0.074
        c0.007,0.01,0.007,0.01,0.007,0.01c0.406,1.572,1.79,2.591,3.327,2.626c-0.042,0.412-0.021,0.821,0.092,1.272
        c0.07,0.269,0.19,0.55,0.328,0.8c-0.603,0.821-0.856,1.911-0.563,2.975c0.289,1.121,1.081,1.977,2.083,2.358
        c-0.222,0.479-0.338,1.021-0.331,1.579c-1.523,0.711-2.383,2.421-1.935,4.092c0.49,1.885,2.421,2.999,4.296,2.506
        c0.197-0.061,0.395-0.113,0.585-0.205c0.014,0.092,0.029,0.188,0.056,0.296c0.494,1.868,2.418,2.992,4.3,2.485
        c1.875-0.483,2.993-2.4,2.503-4.29c-0.035-0.096-0.067-0.183-0.106-0.282c0.698,0.282,1.487,0.356,2.28,0.148
        c1.872-0.501,2.993-2.411,2.503-4.29c-0.25-0.923-0.832-1.649-1.579-2.104c0.138-0.169,0.25-0.331,0.363-0.519
        c0.542,0.423,1.29,0.6,2.016,0.423c1.254-0.328,2.009-1.604,1.688-2.873c-0.018-0.074-0.032-0.134-0.067-0.198
        c0.465,0.198,1.001,0.254,1.53,0.113c1.007-0.271,1.685-1.138,1.741-2.125c1.776-0.564,2.812-2.422,2.333-4.241
        c-0.084-0.325-0.218-0.627-0.38-0.899c0.063-0.18,0.113-0.367,0.127-0.567c0.483,0.229,1.036,0.3,1.597,0.134
        c1.259-0.311,2.016-1.608,1.695-2.845c-0.028-0.091-0.06-0.183-0.099-0.264c0.071-0.3,0.099-0.599,0.084-0.91
        c0.099,0,0.198-0.007,0.289-0.035C262.404,201.039,263.165,199.739,262.826,198.491z M203.364,195.478
        c0.021,0.052,0.021,0.12,0.029,0.169c0.021,0.067,0.042,0.12,0.06,0.194c-0.018,0.021-0.038,0.029-0.067,0.046
        c-0.032-0.049-0.063-0.12-0.098-0.172C203.322,195.622,203.34,195.555,203.364,195.478z M199.015,187.19
        c0.021,0.032,0.046,0.057,0.078,0.103c-0.113,0.029-0.222,0.039-0.325,0.091C198.853,187.322,198.938,187.265,199.015,187.19z
         M177.408,199.256c-0.024,0.071-0.039,0.159-0.039,0.226c-0.018-0.066-0.031-0.141-0.053-0.201
        C177.352,199.281,177.384,199.256,177.408,199.256z M233.691,186.659c0.081,0.077,0.166,0.148,0.25,0.208
        c-0.109-0.024-0.214-0.074-0.328-0.103C233.642,186.736,233.67,186.718,233.691,186.659z M229.314,195.118
        c0.01-0.042,0.014-0.098,0.028-0.151c0.028,0.07,0.056,0.151,0.085,0.243c-0.043,0.032-0.071,0.092-0.106,0.163
        c-0.018-0.025-0.042-0.025-0.063-0.039C229.278,195.266,229.303,195.186,229.314,195.118z"/>
    <path fill="#E6E7E8" d="M246.641,273.381v97.775h-59.652v-97.775l17.99-7.617c1.77,4.177,6.458,7.155,11.981,7.155
        c5.484,0,10.154-2.936,11.949-7.046L246.641,273.381z"/>
    <polygon fill="#5C8BAA" points="211.517,281.653 202.843,266.606 184.395,274.403 184.395,391.522 211.517,391.522     "/>
    <polygon fill="#5C8BAA" points="231.112,266.733 222.43,281.77 222.43,391.649 249.553,391.649 249.553,274.523    "/>
    <polygon fill="#517B93" points="211.503,281.664 197.281,267.541 204.443,262.764 213.516,276.179     "/>
    <polygon opacity="0.2" fill="#231F20" points="206.491,282.086 197.323,267.523 203.957,263.339 213.562,276.165   "/>
    <polygon fill="#5C8BAA" points="206.389,280.949 197.323,267.523 204.479,262.758 213.562,276.165     "/>
    <polygon fill="#517B93" points="222.462,281.664 236.694,267.541 229.532,262.764 220.467,276.179     "/>
    <polygon opacity="0.2" fill="#231F20" points="227.481,282.086 236.652,267.523 230.018,263.339 220.42,276.165    "/>
    <polygon fill="#5C8BAA" points="227.579,280.949 236.652,267.523 229.494,262.758 220.42,276.165  "/>
</g>
</svg>
  
</div>
```